# ajaxStart not working when performing ajax call on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm currently having an issue with ajaxStart/Stop.
When I enter 4 digits in a inputbox, I will perform an AJAX call (on change of this input box and if digits = 4) and the loader shows correctly.

If the user already submitted the page and visits this page again, the digits are prefilled and the ajax call is performed on page load. This works, however the loader doesn't show.

I call ajaxStart/Stop on document ready:

```
$('document').ready(function () {
    $('#spin').ajaxStart(function () {
        startSpinner();
    });
    $('#spin').ajaxStop(function () {
        stopSpinner();
    });
});
```

and the function that performs the ajax call is outside the document ready:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function fillStreets(postalcode, textfield, selectfield, validationfield, init, copy) {
   PERFORM AJAX CALL HERE
}
</script>
```

Any guesses? I already tried using $(document).ajaxStart etc but it didn't work. The startSpinner() and stopSpinner() are declared before the document.ready so this isn't the issue as well.

Thanks!

Comment: try doing the ajax call in the `window.load` event instead of `document.ready`. In `document.ready` images aren't loaded yet and the browser is still doing some processing. Not sure if it'll fix your problem, but it's worth a shot

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it wrong, as .ajaxStart() and .ajaxStop() are only applicable to $(document) as of jQuery 1.8. Make sure you hava $.ajaxSetup global to true.

```
$.ajaxSetup({global:true});
$('document').ready(function () {

//your ready functions

}).ajaxStart(function () {
    startSpinner();
}).ajaxStop(function () {
    stopSpinner();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, your inline code that calls the AJAX is being performed before the $(document).ready() code, which is why no loader appears. The question is why do you have any inline code at all? Any code that happens on the start of your page should be in the document.ready() handler I would think, which should also fix the issue you describe.

When you say, "the ajax call is performed on page load", I am assuming this code is inline, and not in a onload handler. If it is in an onload handler however, I would still question why it is not in the ready handler as well.

Comment: The function is indeed declared in the inline code. But the function itself is called within the $(document).ready. Could this cause the issue as well?

Comment: Hi @dqhendricks, the code which calls the fillStreets function is also inside the document ready:
`        if ($('#PERSONAL_DATA_POSTCODE').val().length == 4) {
            enableAddress();
            fillCities($('#PERSONAL_DATA_POSTCODE').val(), 'PERSONAL_DATA_CITY', 'PERSONAL_DATA_CITY_SELECT', 'true', '');
            fillStreets($('#PERSONAL_DATA_POSTCODE').val(), 'PERSONAL_DATA_STREET', 'PERSONAL_DATA_STREET_SELECT', 'PERSONAL_DATA_POSTCODE_VALID', 'true', '');
        }`
Does this make more sense to you?